# How to solve ODE with these values given?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a ninth grader and my math teacher gave me this task:

$$
y'(x) = \frac{3}{(x+1)^2} + 2 - 0.02x
$$

$$
y(0) = 0
$$

$$
y(5) = 10
$$

And he said I need to get answer with analytical method. Can you help me solve this?

## edit

I just found out that my classmate got same task but different conditions.

$$
y'(x) = \frac{3}{(x+1)^2} + 2 - 0.02x
$$

$$
y(0) = 0
$$

$$
y(5) = 3
$$

He got the right answer:
$$
y(x) = 31.525 - 31.525  \exp(-0.02x)
$$

Comment: Integrate both sides, what do you get for $y$? It will include a constant of integration.

Comment: that is the problem. we learned about parabola few weeks ago and now he gives us differential equations

Comment: @MerlinG.Hager Are you sure this is $y'(x)$ I think it should be $y''(x)$ as the two conditions make not much sense.

Comment: I do not see how an exponential could arrive here with $y'=...$ or even $y''=...$

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate directly to obtain $$y(x)= C - 0.01 x^2 + 2 x - \frac{3}{(x + 1)} $$ Now you can use the hypothesis $y(0)=0$ and $y(5)=10$, to find the value of $C$. Is it what you mean by analytical method?  Doing this, you will have to solve a linear equation system: $$C-3 = 0\ \ \&  \ C-0.01(5)^2+2(5)-\frac{3}{5+1}=10 $$  which I assume you can solve, but which can be seen as inconsistent, since $C=3$ & $C=0.75$. This is weird.

Comment: This is correct, but as you stated - it's going to give us an inconsistent system. There's only one constant that we need to find, and so ultimately it's enough to say either ${y(0)=0}$ or ${y(5)=10}$ (not both). I suspect that OP has written the question incorrectly

Comment: i just added more info, can you check it please?

Comment: @MerlinG.Hager please check your question, because: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+3%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2B2-0.02x%2C+y%280%29%3D0